# Plug new FFI method into GHC

Tags: haskell, ffi

Is there a way to plug a Haskell function of type

```
myFFI :: (C a) => String -> IO a
```

(where `C` is some typeclass describing the types of variables I can import) into GHC as an FFI scheme so that I can write in my Haskell program stuff like

```
foreign import myFFI "foo" foo :: T1 -> T2
```

that gets compiled into a call to `foo = unsafePerformIO $ myFFI "foo" :: T1 -> T2`?

I imagine this could be done by modifying GHC, but is there a way to do it via a plugin I can write without touching the GHC codebase proper?

Comment: The kinds doesn't appear to match. I think you would have `(T1 -> T2)` == `IO a`, and this doesn't typecheck.

Comment: @Tener, `unsafePerformIO` will perform the IO operation (unsafely, even), which will let the expression be any type `a`, in this case so that `a ~ (T1 -> T2)`.

Comment: I've realized it should be easy to get something good enough by using TH. So now I have `[myFFI|Whatever.x :: T1 -> T2|]` that compiles into `x = unsafePerformIO $ myFFI "Whatever.x" :: T1 -> T2`. Is there a way to make these `unsafePerformIO`s run at startup instead of lazily?

Comment: Why are you using `unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: @DonStewart: as opposed to what? The whole point of this would be to use those pure functions from pure code.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to dynamically interpret the string. Then yes, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the comments (since the main question is answered with "use TH"), you can use TH as well to collect a list of all the names you've thus bound. Then, at startup, an `init` call can walk through that and force them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the second argument be in the IO monad in the first place.

```
foreign import ccall sin :: Double -> Double
```

is perfectly legit, but leads to undefined behavior if sin is impure.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question... I need to do IO to load my function by name. That's the part I'd like to do at compile time. This is completely independent of whether the function I load (the `a`) is pure or not.